# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<') use an array instead

Tags: react-native

```
async signIn() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(URI + '/api/login', {
                              method: 'POST',
                              headers: {
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                              },
                              body: JSON.stringify({

                                  username: this.state.username,
                                  password: this.state.password,

                              })
                            });
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          let access_token = responseJson.access_token;
          console.log(responseJson.access_token);
          //On success we will store the access_token in the AsyncStorage
          this.storeToken(responseJson.access_token);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{AccessToken:access_token});
          //this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      } else {
          //Handle error
          let errors = responseJson.errors; 
          if (errors) {
          let err = JSON.stringify(errors);
          throw err;  
        }else{
          let error = responseJson.error;
          let err = JSON.stringify(error);
          throw err;
      }
        }

    } catch(error) {
        this.setState({err: error});
        console.log("error " + error);
    }
  }
```

Day wisely the react-native is updated and new methods were implemented.
 using these codes day before was running but now the error pop ups ,now i can't fix these code . please let me know why these happpens

Comment: probably URI + '/api/login' returns invalid json. I was seeing that error message when my php api returns an error. It has html tags, and because of that it just cant parse the json

Comment: so hw to fix it ? should i use full url

Comment: And while i am using postman and it is working